# Connected app Consumer Key and Consumer Secret are not working after sandbox refresh :(

Tags: community, rest-api, integration, oauth2

I got problem with salesforce connected app Consumer Key and Consumer Secret in Full sandbox after every refresh. When I create a new connected app and use it's key and secret, it is working. What could be the issue? Is it copying the the production connected app key & scret to full sandbox or is it invalidating the existing connected apps key & secret on every refresh?

Is there a way such that we can avoid overriding of connected app details on sandbox so that the existing other applications which are connecting to Salesforce via connected app are not required to change Consumer key and  Secrets.
 Please provide your valuable suggestions.